# Internal axis rotation of hand model in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to rotate both the arms in such a way that the palm faces the sky. 
Attempt 1: I had used the HTC trackers mounted to the wrist. But, this causes twisting of the wrists. 
Attempt 2: I had used the rotation transform option. but, this caused a whole 180 rotation with a flip of hands. (right hand became left hand and vice versa)

I've shown both these pictures in the links below. 
How do i rotate both the arms separately? Unity masters please helppp !
[Attempt 2's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YxW3.png)
[Attempt 1's image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy8M8.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are only turning your hand in the game. but in real life, if you put your hands out in front of you with the palm down and turn them so the palm is facing the ceiling you see your forearms rotate too. So I think you should not only rotate the hands but also the forearms to a degree.

Comment: I do turn my hands in real life too. Inspite of that, there's no change observed on unity.

Comment: no i mean that if you turn your hands you also rotate your forearm. in the game your forearm is not rotating at all (like it would in real life) so i suggest when the wrist turns in the game you should also turn the forearm in game too